# Java for loop variable no where to refer

Tags: java, datetime, variables, for-loop

When I read the book Head First Java, I saw the following code in the Date chapter.

My question is the for loop, in the for loop { } :there is no code using the variable "x", so why the code use for loop here?  Does it mean anything?

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
class FullMoons{
    static int DAY_IM = 1000*60*60*24;
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2004,0,7,15,40);
    long day1 = c.getTimeInMillis();
    for(int x =0; x <60; x++){
      day1 += (DAY_IM * 29.52)
      c.setTimeInMillis(day1);
      out.println(String.format("full moon on %tc"),c)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: it's just an iterator variable you don't need to use it do you?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x = 0; x < 60; x++){
      day1 += (DAY_IM * 29.52)
      c.setTimeInMillis(day1);
      out.println(String.format("full moon on %tc"),c)
}
```

The code above means: repeat 60 times the code inside {...}.

Comment: Got it !! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int x =0; x <60; x++){
  day1 += (DAY_IM * 29.52)
  c.setTimeInMillis(day1);
  out.println(String.format("full moon on %tc"),c)
  }
```

You are correct in that x is never used inside this loop, but this is essentially saying

- count from 0 to 59 - `int x =0; x <60;`
- execute the contents of this loop once on each number
- increment your count by one each time you finish executing the contents of it - `x++`

You could however also use the variable x inside this loop if you wanted, and it would be the value of the variable at that time through the loop.
Maybe it's easier to understand if it was called count? eg:

```
for(int count = 0; count < 60; count++){

}
```

You could also use a while loop in place of this, like:

```
 int count = 0;  
while (count < 60) {
    // loop content    
count++
}
```